# How can I make shapes not draw over each other in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a line that extends out to the spiraling circles on the screen, with the circle constantly drawing a spiral shape, but the line simply growing longer as an "tether" from the center of sorts. However, the line seems to keep drawing over the shape when I try to fill over it. How can I cover the line, but not the previously drawn versions of the spiral?

(ex: trying to make something like the visualized sine and cosine graphs with a unit circle gif)

```py
import pygame
import math 
import time

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (125, 0, 255)
GREEN = (85, 235, 52)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))

screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.update

running = True
should_update = False

dtheta = 0.5
theta = 0

ray_len = 100

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False

    ray = (350, 350)
    x = ray[0] + math.cos(math.radians(theta)) * ray_len
    y = ray[1] + math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * ray_len 

    theta = theta - dtheta
    ray_len = ray_len + 0.1

    line = pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, ray, (x, y), 5)

    screen.fill(BLACK, line)
    line = pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, ray, (x, y), 5)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (x + 20, y + 20), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (x, y), 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (x + 40, y + 40), 5)



    a = False
    b = False
    c = False
    d = False

    if  300 < x < 400 and 150 < y < 350:
        a = True

    # if should_update:
    #     pygame.display.update()
    #     should_update = False

        ## print(event)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(100)
```

I tried filling the blue line after each time it drew with a black one, but then it just overwrote the entire screen in the area it crossed.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.draw.line`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) but the bounding rectangle of the area affected by the draw operation. So your approach will never work.
Create a `pygame.Surface` the size of the screen (`draw_surface`) and draw the circles on that surface. `blit` the surface on the screen in each frame and afterwards draw the line on the screen:

```py
import pygame
import math 

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

draw_surface = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

running = True
dtheta = 0.5
theta = 0
ray_len = 100

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False

    ray = (350, 350)
    x = ray[0] + math.cos(math.radians(theta)) * ray_len
    y = ray[1] + math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * ray_len 

    theta = theta - dtheta
    ray_len = ray_len + 0.1

    pygame.draw.circle(draw_surface, "blue", (x + 20, y + 20), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(draw_surface, "red", (x, y), 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(draw_surface, "yellow", (x + 40, y + 40), 5)
 
    screen.blit(draw_surface, (0, 0))    
    pygame.draw.line(screen, "blue", ray, (x, y), 5)      
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)
```

[image]